How to create a drop down that works with my mobile friendly navbar
I'm working on a basic HTML, CSS, & JavaScript website. I currently have a navbar that is mobile friendly and has a fun little animation when you click on the hamburger menu. I'm having a problem where I'm trying to create a dropdown for one of the navigation options working for mobile friendly viewing. I'm uncertain of how to make this work.
Expected is a dropdown menu that will work with my mobile friendly navbar.


const navEl = document.querySelector('.nav');
const hamburgerEl = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const navItemsEls = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

hamburgerEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navEl.classList.toggle('nav-open');
    hamburgerEl.classList.toggle('hamburger-open');
});

navItemsEls.forEach(navItemsEl => {
    navItemsEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navEl.classList.remove('nav-open');
        hamburgerEl.classList.remove('hamburger-open');
    });
});
/* RESET */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
/* BASE STYLE */
body {
    background-color: #e8f0f7;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    min-height: 500vh;
}


/* NORMAL STYLES */
.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: rgb(19, 22, 26);
}

.navbar-content {
    min-height: 60px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo-img {
    height: 30px;
}

.logo-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
}
.nav {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 40px;
}

.nav-link{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.nav-link:hover, .nav-link:focus {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.hamburger {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.bar {
    height: 2px;
    width: 27px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 5px 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* For JS */
.nav-open {
    left: 50% !important;
}

.hamburger-open .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger-open .bar:nth-child(2) {
    transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger-open .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(-45deg);
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 60px;
        left: -100%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        background-color: rgb(19, 22, 26);
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0 25px;
    }

    .nav-list {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        row-gap: 20px;
    }

    .nav-link {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
    .top-bar__content {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NavBar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <script defer src="script2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="root">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-content">
                    <a href="#" class="logo">
                        <img src="media/insert logo img here" alt="" class="logo-img">
                    </a>
                    <nav class="nav">
                        <ul class="nav-list">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropbtn">Products</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-content">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dropdown one</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dropdown two</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-tem">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="hamburger">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Most simple answer would be to add this into your css:
 .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}
.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
}

Later on you can add id in html to the dropdown-content and modify js according to your needs (make it to show when is click Products, after clicking somewhere else to hide it etc.)
